# How to filter select box options using jQuery with unrelated option values?

Tags: jquery

I need help with filtering out select box options.
I have selection box like this one

```
  <select id="food-category">
  <option value="Fruits">Fruits</option>
  <option value="Vegetables">Vegetables</option></select>
</select>

<select id="food-subcategory">
  <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
  <option value="Kiwi">Kiwi</option>
  <option value="Asparagus">Asparagus</option>
  <option value="Carrot">Carrot</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to filter the options in the second select box based on the chosen options in the first one.

I've found a similar question
[How to filter select box options with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27650217/how-to-filter-select-box-options-with-jquery)
which has an answer that works well if the second option values are name-related to the first ones, but in my case, these are completely unrelated.

So if I select `Vegetables` in the first one, I want to have `Asparagus` and `Carrot` as available options in the second one.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: So your computer should know what is a fruit and what a vegetable without being told? Sounds a bit impossible for me

Comment: How would you, in words (not code), know which ones to filter?  They may as well be X,Y and A,B.C,D.

Comment: Your linked answer is not "name related" (not sure what that means) - they have a `data-` attribute which identifies which option in the 2nd should be chosen for each option in the first, eg `<option data-category="fruit">Banana</option>`.  This is the easiest solution.  An alternative solution would be to have an array/object which defines fruit and vegetables.

Comment: Welcome! One alternative solution is to merge them into a single select and use [`optgroup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) to group them by category.

Comment: I'm sorry I pasted the wrong answer; I've edited it, in the answer first option values are `basic` and `premium` and the second are `basic_montly`, `basic_yearly`, `premium_montly` and `premium_yearly`

Comment: Ok, so use the solution provided in your other link :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27650217/how-to-filter-select-box-options-with-jquery  *you* need to provide some way that the options are connected.

Answer (score 0):

At first we should mention that Banana is a Fruit for example. As a solution we can store this  category in data attribute so we can understand which options show be disabled or enabled.
Next we created onChange callback where we clean all disabled attribute, and disable all non Fruits.

```js
$('#food-category').change(function() {
  $('#food-subcategory [data-category]').removeAttr('disabled');
  $('#food-subcategory :not([data-category='+$(this).val()+'])').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
}).change()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="food-category">
  <option value="Fruits">Fruits</option>
  <option value="Vegetables">Vegetables</option></select>
</select>

<select id="food-subcategory">
  <option value="Banana" data-category="Fruits">Banana</option>
  <option value="Kiwi" data-category="Fruits">Kiwi</option>
  <option value="Asparagus" data-category="Vegetables">Asparagus</option>
  <option value="Carrot" data-category="Vegetables">Carrot</option>
</select>
```